# Cannot enable In-App Purchase in iOS App ID Settings

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

When I go to `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` and then go to `iOS App ID Settings` and then click on my bundle id, the only element that is enabled is `Game Center`. My problem is that i need to enable In-App Purchase but I can't seem to do it.

When I click Edit, The check box for In-App Purchase is greyed out. I can't enable it this way... why not?

I've uploaded a new Xcode project to the app store with In-App Purchase enabled in `Capabilities` and its supposed to update the App Id automatically. However nothing changes. 
Another person had the same problem on here, and they solved it that way, however the change was delayed for some reason, why would the change take place at a delayed time?

I've created other bundle id's manually and they have game center in-app-purchase enabled. So I'm just lost on how to change this first one I made through xcode.

I cant delete it either because it's being used by itunes connect, and I can't delete that project either.

Any suggestions?